# PubsubMessage and MessageMetadata not found in pubsub lite receving message

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsublite

i am following below documentation of PubSub lite and trying to recieving message which i have publish using below code. Getting error in callback function.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/subscribing
Publishing message

```
#code for publishing message which runs fine
import json
from google.cloud.pubsublite.cloudpubsub import PublisherClient
from google.cloud.pubsublite.types import (
    CloudRegion,
    CloudZone,
    MessageMetadata,
    TopicPath,
)

# TODO(developer):
project_number = 97466088
cloud_region = "us-west1"
zone_id = "b"
topic_id = "mytestopic"
# num_messages = 100

location = CloudZone(CloudRegion(cloud_region), zone_id)
topic_path = TopicPath(project_number, location, topic_id)

# PublisherClient() must be used in a `with` block or have __enter__() called before use.
with PublisherClient() as publisher_client:
    f = open('fivekey_10000.json')
    data = json.load(f)
    #file = open("data_new_file.txt", "r")
    #file1 = file.read().split("\n")
    for message in data.items():
        data = message[0].encode("utf-8")
        ordering_key = message[1]
        # Messages of the same ordering key will always get published to the same partition.
        # When ordering_key is unset, messsages can get published ot different partitions if
        # more than one partition exists for the topic.
        api_future = publisher_client.publish(
            topic_path, data=data, ordering_key=ordering_key)
        # result() blocks. To resolve api futures asynchronously, use add_done_callback().
        message_id = api_future.result()
        message_metadata = MessageMetadata.decode(message_id)
        print(
            f"Published {data} to partition {message_metadata.partition.value} and offset {message_metadata.cursor.offset}."
        )

print(
    f"Published messages with ordering keys to {topic_path}."
)
```

Comment: Could you share the error and it's traceback? Also, to replicate the setup at my end could you share the sample of your json file?

Answer (score 0):

I tried publishing messages to the topic using ordering keys as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/publishing#using_ordering_keys) documentation.

To receive the messages from subscription you need to request messages from Lite subscription. This can be done through the gcloud command line or any [client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/subscribing#receiving_messages). Do note that  Pub/Sub lite topics and subscriptions are zonal resources ie. they need to be in the same zone and project.

While receiving the messages, the callback function takes `Pubsub Message` as it’s only argument and acknowledges the message displaying the message data and metadata respectively.

```
def callback(message: PubsubMessage):
    message_data = message.data.decode("utf-8")
    metadata = MessageMetadata.decode(message.message_id)
    print(
        f"Received {message_data} of ordering key {message.ordering_key} with id {metadata}."
    )
    message.ack()
```

If you’re still facing issues please provide more information on the error along with the traceback.